# Как в Linux добавить корневой сертификат для браузеров через Net.Core?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

Генерировал свой CA сертификат.
Если импортировать из браузера то все работает.
Но нужно добавить в доверенные кодом.
Я использовал такой код:

```
void AddSerts(NetX509Cert.X509Certificate2 Cert) {

   var StoreLocation = NetX509Cert.StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
   var StoreName = NetX509Cert.StoreName.Root;

   NetX509Cert.X509Store store = new NetX509Cert.X509Store(StoreName, StoreLocation);
   store.Open(NetX509Cert.OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
   store.Add(Cert);
   store.Close();
}
```

Под windows работает, под Linux не работает.
Код работает с повышением прав - т.е. под суперпользователем.
Исключения при работе кода не возникают.
Как и не появляется сертификат в списке доверенных.

Не подскажите куда копать?

Comment: [тут](https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html) посмотрите. Не уверен, что получится обойтись без командной строки.

Comment: @rdon не получается. Вернее команды выполнены, сертификат в бандл добавлен, но браузеры его не видят....
У лисы и у хрома свои хранилища сертификатов? они штатными не пользуются?